# Location change of child as gaming mode activated

Tags: game-engine, parent

I have two cylinders, one is the puck, other is the handle. The handle is child of the puck. They both have dynamic physics.
I use python to define their motion.
As soon as I hit p and enter gaming/testing mode, their locations are changed. But the handle has more dramatical location change than the puck.

[image]

Here is two photos of before and after hitting p:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

I cannot figure out why this sudden change of location and getting compressed in y direction.

Here is my script:

```
import bge


def main():
    cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
    keyboard = bge.logic.keyboard
    puck = cont.owner


    # sensors
    bottom_edge_collision = cont.sensors["bottom_edge"]

    # keys
    r_pressed = bge.logic.KX_INPUT_JUST_ACTIVATED == keyboard.events[bge.events.RKEY]

    if r_pressed:
        scene.restart()
        print("rsrt", puck.localPosition)


main()
```

Here is my blend file:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dcXSZ7HHZH9h8f6KFJWUsVmuRl69o6bd?usp=sharing

Comment: You do not need "main()" and "def main()". It makes the code harder to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your blend file we can only guess. The most likely candidate is a non-unit scale. Select the objects, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and choose "Scale". This applies the object-level scale factor to the mesh itself, and resets the object-level scale to (1, 1, 1).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an old bug of Blender (which can't be compensated by the BGE).

**in Blender:**

- Unparent the objects.
- Reset both objects to the scene origin (Rot, Pos, Scale).
- Parent them together
- move the parent to the desired location.

Comment: When I use no scale, your solution is perfect. But when I make the handle slimmer, same problem occurs. How can I make a thin-long handle other than using scale?

Comment: As mentioned in the other answer, apply the scale, which deforms the vertices rather than the object.